# password_hash still hashes and stores an undefined variable

Tags: php, password-hash

I have a script which successfully writes to the database. 
However, when I change the variable name `$password1` or `$password9` or `$password34` and save the script, the script still works and a new entry in the DB appears with all the fields filled out including the password field.

```
$password0 = trim($_POST['password1']);
$hashed_passcode = password_hash($password4, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, 'ssss', $first_name, $last_name, $email, $hashed_passcode);
```

Above is an example, where I changed the variable to `$password0`. and when I hash it the variable is `$password4`. I resubmit the form and it still works. How can this be?

Comment: You are hashing an undefined variable. It has the same affect as hashing an empty string. If this is running an insert the behavior makes sense. Without `$q` its hard to tell what you are doing. If you are running a `select` it should fail.

Comment: @user3783243 Right you are. Btw, I didn't see your comment when I was writing my answer.

Comment: $password0 = trim($_POST['password1']);
        $hashed_passcode = password_hash($password4, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        require('mysqli_connect.php');

        //Creating a query
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password, registration_date)";
        $query .= "VALUES(?,?,?,?,NOW() )";

        $q = mysqli_stmt_init($dbcon);

        mysqli_stmt_prepare($q, $query);

Comment: ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Ah... right you are there @JayBlanchard Good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason being is that it will create a hash alright, it just won't store the hash associated with the actual password you want to store.

Having all [error reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) set though, would have signaled an undefined variable.

**Note:** [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) only hashes passwords and does not show any type of error, that isn't its job to do that, it's the error handling on the server that does.

Comment: @IgorLebedev You're most welcome Igor, glad I could be of help. You know though, I am pretty sure that I've never seen a question like yours asked and to think that I already knew that before someone asked, heh. I think your question will help others also, *cheers!*

Comment: @IgorLebedev On an added note and seeing that you are new to this. Make sure that the length of the password column in your database is long enough to store the hash. The manual states 60 min. length but they also suggest using 255. Unless you knew that already ;-) If not, make sure it is. Because your verifying the password will fail and silently if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for this, yes I did know this! I have taken it into consideration.  Is it better to use char(255)  when storing passwords?

Comment: You're welcome @IgorLebedev Yes. if you see the manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php you will see *"(255 characters would be a good choice)"*. ;-) and more information in there on the function. There's also a better algo to use if you're running this off a server with PHP 7+. This being "ARGON2".